# If I wanted to create a GUI for wget in c++.. where would I start?

Tags: c++, wget

Question is the title.

I'm sorry, I suppose I need to specify.

I'm not sure what commands or what code to use to actually link wget to a gui.

I have two weeks until classes start and I just want to Create something.

Comment: I assume you will be using a framework like Qt, wxwidgets, FLTK, MFC ...

Comment: c++ itself has no GUI. However there are lots of c++ GUI frameworks. Again I assume in a class you will be told what GUI framework to use. Since a class can not cover dozens of different frameworks.

Comment: You start a new process that executes wget.

Comment: Closing this question was right, but I think "Too Broad" is the wrong reason.  This question is off-topic because you are asking for a list of things -- in this case, a list of GUI frameworks.

Comment: Are you creating a web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#Based_on_C.2B.2B_.28including_bindings_to_other_languages.29) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html). There are numerous widget toolkits for C++.

Since wget is not a HTTP library, but an application, calling this using system() or similar calls is disrecommended.

I advise you to use a HTTP C/C++ library.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try and answer my question.  I'm a programing novice and all I really have so far is pseudo code.

I want to create a gui for wget, [or create something similar in c++ code] but i'm not sure where to start.